# Javascript : setTimeout use on an anonymous function expression

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I recently started learning javascript to help maintain some stuff and ran into this issue today:

```
this.moveChar = function(){  
    // body here
    setTimeout(moveChar,1000);
}

this.initialise= function(){
    this.moveChar();
}
```

When initialise is called, I expected moveChar to be called, then repeated call itself once every 1000ms

However, what actually happens is moveChar gets called once then that's it. Based on other stackoverflow posts I read, I suspected it might be something to do with the function being expressed rather than declared. I have tried to use

```
this.moveChar = function recMove(){  
    // body here
    setTimeout(recMove,1000);
}
```

without luck either.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

EDIT: Main thing I need to do is have the moveChar function called once every second. If there is a better approach than setTimeout recursion, I'm open to it

Comment: Are you using `this` in side `body here`? If so, you should bind correct context while call.

Comment: First if you wish to run a function after every specific delay, use `setInterval`. Second, when you do `setTimeout(moveChar,1000);`, JS will look for a variable with name `moveChar` and will not find anything. `moveChar` is a part of an object and has to be accessed as `object.moveChar` in your case `this.moveChar`. Now since you are looping recursively, you will have to bind `this` again. so your code becomes `setTimeout(this.moveChar.bind(this), 1000)`

Comment: yes the function moveChar uses some global variables by referring to them using this.VARIABLENAME if that's what you mean? Can you elaborate on the binding to context part?

Comment: @Rajesh, `setInterval` is completely other feature. with tail `setTimeout` you'll never get two calls at same time.

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you very much that fixed it completely. I tried setInterval earlier but it did not work, possible due to me not binding it properly

Comment: @vp_arth True that but that will happen if some function takes a lot of time. This approach is appropriate if you wish to implement a pooling mechanism but if its a simple function which needs to be executed after every 1s, `setInterval` is what you should use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.moveChar` is not the same as `moveChar`, unless `this` is the global scope object like `window`.

`this.moveChar` is a property on an object, while `moveChar` would reference any variable in a visible scope chain.

You can change it to a couple of things in order to keep scope of whatever object is being used:

**Using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**

```
this.moveChar = function(){  
    // body here
    setTimeout(()=>this.moveChar(),1000);
}
```

**Using [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**

```
this.moveChar = function(){  
    // body here
    setTimeout(this.moveChar.bind(this),1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `this` in `side body` here?
If so, you should bind correct context while call.

```
this.moveChar = function(){  
    // body here
    setTimeout(this.moveChar.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Or use anonymous function:

```
this.moveChar = function(){  
    // body here
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      that.moveChar();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Or arrow function:

```
this.moveChar = function(){  
    // body here
    setTimeout(() => this.moveChar(), 1000);
}
```

Same notes apply to `setInterval` variant:

```
this.initialise= function(){
   setInterval(this.moveChar.bind(this), 1000);
   // var that = this;
   // setInterval(function(){that.moveChar();}, 1000);

   // setInterval(() => this.moveChar(), 1000);
}
```

Comment: He needs to repeat the execution, `setInterval` is needed here.

Comment: This `setTimeout` repeats the exeution. Why `setInterval` need here?

Comment: Check the second **tip** on this [W3Schools Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: See `A clock created with timing events` on the same page

Comment: You are right, if we use recursion then we can also achieve the repetition. But `setInterval` would have been easier to read if only repetition was required.

Comment: there is difference: `setInterval` don't wait previous calls, so it can spam calls.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using `setInterval()` which is the more appropriate API for this task.

What `setInterval()` does is - it will repeatedly call the given function upon a certain interval is reached.

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

**Quote:**

> Repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed
>   time delay between each call. Returns an intervalID.

**Example:**

Assuming `moveChar()` contains your operation logic. Then to repeat it you'll do this 1 line.

```
let moveChar = function(){  
    // Do stuff
    console.log("Hi thanks for calling me!");
}

setInterval(moveChar, 1000);
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not execute a single iteration of the moveChar function for some reason

Comment: @kcns15 works on my machine at work. Did u just copy paste the code above and test it or u did some minor mods to it. If u do care to show your current code? Happy to assist further.

Answer (score -2):

```
   this.moveChar = function(){  
       // body here
     alert('called moveChar');
  }

this.initialise= function(){
     setInterval(function(){moveChar();},1000);
}

 this.initialise();//call here
```

Comment: First, just putting code is not a good answer. You should explain what you have changed. Second, run your code before and then put it here.